# Livewire: Multiple root elements detected. This is not supported

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, livewires

I want to make button when i press on it the number of item increase but it doesn't work because of this error

> Livewire: Multiple root elements detected. This is not supported. See docs for more information https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubles

**My route in php file**

```
<div class="sb-input-number-frame">

   <a class="sb-input-number-btn sb-sub" href="#" wire:click.prevent="decreaseQuantity('{{$item->rowId}}')">-</a>
   <input type="text" name="product-quatity" value="{{$item->qty}}" data-max="120" pattern="[0-9]*" >
   <a class="sb-input-number-btn sb-add"  href="#" wire:click.prevent="increaseQuantity('{{ $item->rowId }}">+</a>

 </div>
```

**My component code**

```
 public function increaseQuantity($rowId)
{
    $product = Cart::instance('cart')->get($rowId);
    $qty = $product->qty + 1;
    Cart::instance('cart')->update($rowId, $qty);
    $this->emitTo('cart-count-component', 'refreshComponent');
}
```

Comment: We need more code from you to assist. The error is Because Livewire components enter a Comment and look for the end of the comment in HTML. The error is stating it cant find the end of the comment which is preventing your code from running. I would suggest to first try wrapping your Invocation in a div

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to ensure that you only have one root HTML element, such as a . If you have multiple elements, then wrap everything in a  or another element that suits your layout.

So in our example from above, we have wrapped everything in a  which gets running:

```
   <div> 
<!-- Added this wrapping div -->
  <div class="sb-input-number-frame">

   <a class="sb-input-number-btn sb-sub" href="#" wire:click.prevent="decreaseQuantity('{{$item->rowId}}')">-</a>
   <input type="text" name="product-quatity" value="{{$item->qty}}" data-max="120" pattern="[0-9]*" >
   <a class="sb-input-number-btn sb-add"  href="#" wire:click.prevent="increaseQuantity('{{ $item->rowId }}">+</a>

 </div>
 <!-- Added this closing tag for the wrapping div -->
</div>
```

Comment: I did it but unfortunately it doesn't work